# Swift Change Position of UIBarButtonItem in UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am doing custom a navigation bar with items which y positions are lower than default. I tried many methods:

- `setBackButtonBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:`
- set `CGRectOffset` of custom view
- `UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffset.init(horizontal: X, vertical: Y), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)`

They made the items appeared in right positions, but I couldn't fire any actions when I clicked/touched on them. I think because I didn't touch the bar items, they were only the appearances/ copy views/images of these item.

[image]

Could anybody help me to resolve this problem?

My code:

```
let lblTitle = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 28))
            lblTitle.text = FMLStringLocale("APP_name")
            lblTitle.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            lblTitle.font = ROBOTO_THIN_24
            lblTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
            lblTitle.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            lblTitle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(6, 11)

            let lblTitleContainer = UIView(frame: lblTitle.frame)
            lblTitleContainer.addSubview(lblTitle)
            let leftTitle = UIBarButtonItem(customView: lblTitleContainer)
            navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftTitle

            let rightView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 134, 22))
            rightView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            rightView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 18)

            let imvUSFlag = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "icon_us"))
            imvUSFlag.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 19, 13)
            imvUSFlag.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-2, 20)

            rightView.addSubview(imvUSFlag)

            let switcher = UISwitch(frame: CGRectMake(imvUSFlag.frame.maxX - 5, 12, 31, 16))
            switcher.setOn(false, animated: false)
            switcher.addTarget(self, action: Selector("tapToChangeLanguage:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
            switcher.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5)

//            let switchContainer = UIView(frame: switcher.frame)
//            switchContainer.addSubview(switcher)

            rightView.addSubview(switcher)

            let imvFRFlag = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "icon_france"))
            imvFRFlag.frame = CGRectMake(switcher.frame.maxX + 6, 0, 19, 14)
            imvFRFlag.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 20)

            rightView.addSubview(imvFRFlag)

            let btnMenu = UIButton()
            btnMenu.setImage(UIImage(named : "icon_menu"), forState: .Normal)
            btnMenu.frame = CGRectMake(imvFRFlag.frame.maxX + 30, 0, 23, 21)
            btnMenu.addTarget(self, action: "tapToMenu:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            btnMenu.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 18)

            rightView.addSubview(btnMenu)
            rightView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 18)

            let rightViewItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: rightView)

            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightViewItem

            navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .BlackTranslucent
            navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
            navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Comment: I am sorry about this mistake. I have just inserted code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you can't tap your button `btnMenu` is that you have positioned `btnMenu` *outside* the frame of its superview `rightView`. A subview outside its superview cannot receive touches.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the code and it's working now. It's so great if you can review my code and maybe improve it.

Comment: Oh. I am so impolite. Sorry. :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I resolved my problem:

Check my new code:

```
let lblTitle = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(7, 32, 100, 28))
            lblTitle.text = FMLStringLocale("APP_name")
            lblTitle.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            lblTitle.font = ROBOTO_THIN_24
            lblTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
            lblTitle.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

            let lblTitleContainer = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 64))
//            lblTitleContainer.bounds = CGRectOffset(lblTitleContainer.bounds, -6, -32)
            lblTitleContainer.addSubview(lblTitle)

            let leftTitle = UIBarButtonItem(customView: lblTitleContainer)
            navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftTitle

            let rightView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 134, 64))
//            rightView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
//            rightView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 18)

            let imvUSFlag = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "icon_us"))
            imvUSFlag.frame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 18, 12)

            rightView.addSubview(imvUSFlag)

            let switcher = UISwitch(frame: CGRectMake(imvUSFlag.frame.maxX - 5, 32, 31, 16))
            switcher.setOn(false, animated: false)
            switcher.addTarget(self, action: Selector("tapToChangeLanguage:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
            switcher.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.45)


            let switchContainer = UIView(frame: switcher.frame)
            switchContainer.addSubview(switcher)

            rightView.addSubview(switcher)

            let imvFRFlag = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "icon_france"))
            imvFRFlag.frame = CGRectMake(switcher.frame.maxX + 6, 40, 18, 12)

            rightView.addSubview(imvFRFlag)

            let btnMenu = UIButton()
            btnMenu.setImage(UIImage(named : "icon_menu"), forState: .Normal)
            btnMenu.frame = CGRectMake(imvFRFlag.frame.maxX + 30, 35, 23, 21)
            btnMenu.addTarget(self, action: "tapToMenu:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

            rightView.addSubview(btnMenu)

            let rightViewItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: rightView)

            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightViewItem

            navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .BlackTranslucent
            navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
            navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```